# How to add 2 columns to an HTML table dynamically created using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

The function below does check if the row of data coming in is valid and sets the 06th column to an input field, where the price will be informed. The data, however, has 07 "columns", but I'd need to add two more and I can't wrap my head around getting it done:

1st additional column, or `td` would be a total field, which will get refreshed as the user informs the price. I'll create a function for that later;

02nd additional column would be a check box.

This is what I have so far:

**Sample Data**

```
[
 ["Arms","Black-830011","","100 cot",1.63,273,"","178 m"],
 ["Arms2","Black-830011","","97 cot/3 span",1,267,"","176 m"]
]
```

**Code**

```js
function loadItems() {
    const orderPo = document.getElementById('selectOrderPo');
    const selectedOrderPo = orderPo.options[orderPo.selectedIndex].text;

    const supplier = document.getElementById('selectSupplier');
    const selectedSupplier = supplier.options[supplier.selectedIndex].text;

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) {
        if (ar == 'No items were found') {
            var div = document.getElementById('po-items');
            div.innerHTML = "There are no items for this Order PO Number and Supplier chosen above!";
            return;
        }
        if (ar && ar !== undefined && ar.length != 0) {
            var result = "<br><div class='card' id='card'><table class='table table-borderless table-hover table-vcenter' id='dtable'>" +
                "<thead style='white-space: nowrap'>" +
                "<tr>" + //Change table headings to match witht he Google Sheet
                "<th style='width: 4%' class='text-center'>Tela</th>" +
                "<th style='width: 25%' class='text-center'>Color</th>" +
                "<th style='width: 4%' class='text-center'>Pantone</th>" +
                "<th style='width: 3%' class='text-center'>Contenido</th>" +
                "<th style='width: 17%' class='text-center'>Acho(m)</th>" +
                "<th style='width: 12%' class='text-center'>Peso(gsm)</th>" +
                "<th style='width: 24%' class='text-center'>Precio/m (COP)</th>" +
                "<th style='width: 24%' class='text-center'>Metros</th>" +
                "<th style='width: 24%' class='text-center'>Precio Total sin IVA</th>" +
                "<th style='width: 24%' class='text-center'>Sel.</th>" +
                "</tr>" +
                "</thead>" +
                "<tbody>";
            console.log('Dados para a tabela: ' + JSON.stringify(ar))
            for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
                result += "<tr>";
                for (var j = 0; j < ar[i].length; j++) {
                    (j === 6 && isNan(ar[i][4]) === false) ? "<td><input type='number' name='priceField'></td>" : "<td class='align-middle' style='word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center'>" + ar[i][j] + "</td>";
                }
                result += "</tr>";
            }
            result += "</tbody></table></div><br>";
            div = document.getElementById('po-items');
            div.innerHTML = result;
        } else {
            div = document.getElementById('po-items');
            div.innerHTML = "No items found.";
            return;
        }
    }).loadItems(selectedOrderPo, selectedSupplier);
}
```

**Expected Result**
[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `The function below does check if the row of data coming in is valid and sets the 06th column to an input field, where the price will be informed. The data, however, has 07 "columns", but I'd need to add two more`. Can you provide the sample input values and the sample output situation as an image?

Comment: Do you want to add 2 addtional columns before the table is initially displayed?  Or after it has been displayed you click a button or something and 2 additional columns are added to the table?

Comment: Hi, @TheWizEd! Just added an expected result above. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, @Tanaike! Just added an expected result above! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your added information, how about modifying your showing script as follows?

#### From:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
    result += "<tr>";
    for (var j = 0; j < ar[i].length; j++) {
        (j === 6 && isNan(ar[i][4]) === false) ? "<td><input type='number' name='priceField'></td>" : "<td class='align-middle' style='word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center'>" + ar[i][j] + "</td>";
    }
    result += "</tr>";
}
```

#### To:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
  result += "<tr>";
  for (var j = 0; j < ar[i].length; j++) {
      result += (j === 6 && isNaN(ar[i][4]) === false) ? "<td><input type='number' name='priceField'></td>" : "<td class='align-middle' style='word-wrap: break-word;max-width: 160px;text-align:center'>" + ar[i][j] + "</td>";
  }
  result += `<td>0.00</td>`;
  result += `<td><input type="checkbox"></td>`;
  result += "</tr>";
}
```

- `isNan` is `isNaN`.
- In your showing script, `result += "<tr>"` is not updated. Because the values are not added in the loop.
- In order to add 2 columns, I added `result +=` 0.00`and`result += `<td><input type="checkbox"></td>`.

  - About `0.00`, from `I'll create a function for that later;`, I added it as a sample value.
  - Please add the style, id and so on for your actual situation.

Comment: Thank you! Gladt to see it went towards what I had roughly thought of when I was away! Thanks!

Comment: @onit Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.